Litespeed cache purge for specific pages
I've implemented a custom functionality in WordPress to automatically set alert banners (custom_alert post type) to 'draft' status upon expiration, using a custom field alert_expiration_date. When an alert expires, I only want to purge the cache for the pages associated with that alert (defined in the alert_pages custom field), not the entire site. Here's the relevant part of my code:
    add_filter('cron_schedules', 'add_custom_cron_schedule');
    function add_custom_cron_schedule($schedules) {
        if (!isset($schedules["every_two_minutes"])) {
            $schedules['every_two_minutes'] = array(
                'interval' => 120,  // 2 minutes en secondes
                'display' => esc_html__('Every Two Minutes')
            );
        }
        return $schedules;
    }
    
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('expire_alerts_check')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'every_two_minutes', 'expire_alerts_check');
    }
    add_action('expire_alerts_check', 'expire_and_purge_function');
    
    function expire_and_purge_function() {
        $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', current_time('timestamp', 0));
        $args = [
            'post_type' => 'custom_alert',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_query' => [
                [
                    'key' => 'alert_expiration_date',
                    'value' => $today,
                    'compare' => '<=',
                    'type' => 'DATETIME'
                ]
            ]
        ];
        $posts = get_posts($args);
    
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $expiration_date = get_field('alert_expiration_date', $post->ID);
            if ($expiration_date && strtotime($expiration_date) <= strtotime($today)) {
                wp_update_post([
                    'ID' => $post->ID,
                    'post_status' => 'draft'
                ]);
    
                $pages_to_update = get_field('alert_pages', $post->ID);
                if (!empty($pages_to_update)) {
                    purge_pages_cache($pages_to_update);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    function purge_pages_cache($pages_to_update) {
        foreach ($pages_to_update as $page_id) {
            do_action('litespeed_purge_post', $page_id);
            log_purge_action($page_id);
        }
    }

However, I'm encountering an issue where the cache for all pages on the site seems to be purged instead of just the specific pages associated with the expired alert.
